# Extend the Visual Studio Locals/Autos window through code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to extend what appears in the VS Locals/Autos window through code? Like through a Visual Studio Extension? I would like to iterate through the displayed variables and manipulate how they are organized and appear.

I have read up on techniques like using AutoExp.dat and .NatVis, but would like to write code that actively re-arranges the structure of displayed items via C# code. All of our types have a similar structure, and I would like more flexibility than doing this via a massive type-specific file.

I am trying to make it simpler for people to read our generated code structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about what displays when you mouse-over/add a watch, there's the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute:

[Using DebuggerDisplay Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)

[Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)

Oh, almost forgot: for more complicated debugger extensions, you can always create your own Visualizer - this is similar to what you get if you use the little magnifying glass/drop down on a variable during debugging:

[Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx)

[CodeProject - Create a visualizer in 10 lines of code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13127/Create-a-Debugger-Visualizer-in-10-Lines-of-Code)

Comment: I am hoping more to customize the tabled list of variables in the Locals Window itself, as in re-arranging some of the parent hierarchy and adding more descriptive messages at the root level before expanding them.

Comment: @Kunan If you'd like to re-arrange the hierarchy itself then the DebuggerDisplayAttribute won't do, you'll need to check out the DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute instead.